# Is Hausdorff measure regular?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{H}^k$ be a $k$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.
Is it true that
$\mathcal{H}^k (E)=\sup \{\mathcal{H}^k (S)\mid S\subset E \text{ is compact}\}$?

Comment: Related: [Is the Hausdorff outer measure regular?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/128085/13130) *AND* [Are the Hausdorff measures inner regular?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3332127/13130) *AND* [Why is Hausdorff measure Borel regular?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2694539/13130) See also p. 11 of [Howroyd's 1994 Ph.D. dissertation](http://smithsold.gold.ac.uk/jhowroyd/jdhthesis.pdf), which might be useful for a lot of subtle issues you could later be interested in.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro The second and fourth links there aren't working.

Comment: @Perry Ainsworth: The second link is to a question that was turns out was automatically deleted (by "Community") after I wrote my comment, and thus viewable only to those with sufficient $(\geq 10$K?) reputation. QUESTION: I've been looking all over the usual textbooks on geometric measure theory, and I can't seem to find a discussion of the fact whether the Hausdorff measures $\{ H^s : 0 < s < d \}$ are inner regular on $\mathbf{R}^d$. Are they, and if so, is there a standard proof? MY COMMENT [no other comments; no answers]: Isn't this just Theorem 1.6(b) on p. 8 **(continued)**

Comment: of Falconer's *The Geometry of Fractal Sets*? It's only guaranteed to be true for sets of finite $s$-measure (or for analytic sets, if we remove the finiteness condition), however, and I believe (but I haven't double-checked with his paper) that [Besicovitch showed this can fail](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/jlms/s1-29.3.382) when the set has infinite $s$-measure and isn't analytic. See [this manuscript](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.1999.pdf) also.

Comment: To fix the fourth link, try this: John David Howroyd, [**On the Theory of Hausdorff Measures in Metric Spaces**](https://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/id/eprint/10102121/), Ph.D. Dissertation (under David Preiss), University College London, June 1994, iii + 69 pages.